# I have a error with this bot for minecraft

Tags: c#, bots, minecraft

I write this code for a bot for Minecraft 1.12, but it doesn't work, can you help me?

This is the code:

> 

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP.Text, Int32.Parse(PORT.Text));
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Flush();
        BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(stream);

        byte PacketID = 0x35;
        byte ProtocolVersion = 35;
        string Username = "Name";
        Username.PadRight(64, ' ');
        string VerificationKey = password.Text;
        VerificationKey.PadRight(64, ' ');

        wr.Write(PacketID);
        wr.Write(ProtocolVersion);
        wr.Write(Username);
        wr.Write(VerificationKey);

        BinaryReader rea = new BinaryReader(stream);
        richTextBox1.Text = rea.Read().ToString();
    }
}
}
```

I follow-ed this tutorial for make it: https://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=923764

Comment: That's not how packets are formed. See [this](http://wiki.vg/Protocol) for more information

Comment: I understant, thank you.

Comment: @WingerSendon so, how I send a packet?

Comment: The link I sent explains it all well.

Comment: @WingerSendon What should I write for send this in c#:
Packet ID State Bound To Field Name Field Type Notes
0x05 Play Client Entity ID VarInt Player's EID
Player UUID UUID See below for notes on offline mode and NPCs
X Double 
Y Double 
Z Double 
Yaw Angle 
Pitch Angle 
Metadata Entity Metadata

Comment: I don't have a C# example. But here's on in Go: Should be easy to understand. [spawn player packet](https://github.com/wingerse/quartz/blob/master/common/proto/packet/play/spawnplayer.go)| [packet writing and reading](https://github.com/wingerse/quartz/blob/master/common/proto/packet/io.go)| [entity metadata](https://github.com/wingerse/quartz/blob/master/common/encoding/entitymetadata.go#L175-L277)..

Comment: if you still can't understand, I suggest you study TCP and IO in general more.

Comment: @WingerSendon Ok, thank you.